# В датасете даты разного формата, как привести все к единому?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

В основном даты формата YYYY-MM-DD, но есть и DD.MM.YYYY, как привести все даты к одному формату используя питон и пандас? Хочу чтоб все были формата YYYY-MM-DD, можно ли регулярками вытащить неверный формат, а потом каким то образом привести к нужному?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе [mcve] входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Answer (score 5):

В Pandas для парсинга дат в виде строк в `datetime` существует удобная функция [pd.to_datetime()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html), как уже написал @SergFSM в своем ответе.

Но при работе с датами формата `DD.MM.YYYY` или `DD-MM-YYYY` есть одна тонкость - если оба числа (день месяца и номер месяца) не превышают 12, то `pd.to_datetime()` по умолчанию парсит первое число как номер месяца (в американском стиле):

```
In [452]: pd.to_datetime(["2021-09-21", "03.09.2020", "13.12.2020"])
Out[452]: DatetimeIndex(['2021-09-21', '2020-03-09', '2020-12-13'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
# NOTE: ----------------------------->  ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Поэтому я бы сначала спарсил все даты формата `DD.MM.YYYY`, а потом все остальные:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"date": ["2021-09-21", "03.09.2020", "13.12.2020", "04-12-20", "03/01/2000", "blah-blah"]})
```

исходный фрейм:

```
In [468]: df
Out[468]:
         date
0  2021-09-21
1  03.09.2020  # 3 Sep 2020
2  13.12.2020
3    04-12-20  # 4 Dec 2020
4  03/01/2000  # <- `1 Mar 2000` записано в американском стиле 
5   blah-blah
```

парсим даты формата `DD.MM.YYYY`:

```
mask = df["date"].str.contains("^\d{1,2}[.-]\d{1,2}[.-](?:\d{4}|\d{2})")
df.loc[mask, "date"] = pd.to_datetime(df.loc[mask, "date"], dayfirst=True, errors="coerce")
```

после этого парсим оставшиеся даты:

```
df.loc[~mask, "date"] = pd.to_datetime(df.loc[~mask, "date"],  errors="coerce")
```

результат:

```
In [472]: df
Out[472]:
                  date
0  2021-09-21 00:00:00
1  2020-09-03 00:00:00
2  2020-12-13 00:00:00
3  2020-12-04 00:00:00
4  2000-03-01 00:00:00
5                  NaT
```

---

Если у вас в данных нет данных формата `MM/DD/YYYY`, т.е. таких где номер месяца стоит первым числом, тогда решение будет значительно проще:

```
df.loc[:, "date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"], dayfirst=True, errors="coerce")
```

Comment: А параметр `dayfirst=True` нельзя использовать?

Comment: @CrazyElf, можно, если есть уверенность, что в данных не встречаются даты где номер месяца действительно стоит вначале. )

Answer (score 1):

используйте `pandas.to_datetime` , примерно так он работает:

```
pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(['12.31.2020','31-12-2020','31.12.2020','12-31-2020','2020-12-31']))
```

вывод:

```
0   2020-12-31
1   2020-12-31
2   2020-12-31
3   2020-12-31
4   2020-12-31
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```